# pandas: write df to text file - indent df to right by 5 white spaces

Tags: python, pandas, format, dataframe, tostring

I am writing a df to a text file like so:

```
file = open("pptx_comparision_log.txt", "w")
df= df.to_string()
file.write(comp_df)
```

This works fine but how can I indent my df so it sits 5 white spaces to the right.

so from this:

```
                    dim_pptx  qp_pptx
Absolute Radio        0.0739   0.0753
BBC Asian Network     0.0013   0.0013
BBC Radio 1           0.1441   0.1455
BBC Radio 1Xtra       0.0057   0.0058
BBC Radio 2           0.2336   0.2339
```

to:

```
                         dim_pptx  qp_pptx
     Absolute Radio        0.0739   0.0753
     BBC Asian Network     0.0013   0.0013
     BBC Radio 1           0.1441   0.1455
     BBC Radio 1Xtra       0.0057   0.0058
     BBC Radio 2           0.2336   0.2339
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just do it with string manipulation after the conversion by replacing `df.to_string()` with `" "*5 + df.to_string().replace("\n", "\n     ")`.

Comment: This is very elegant.

Comment: Legend! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Riding on @Randy's answer above, wanna suggest a slightly better solution:

```
indent = " " * N
df_str = indent + df.to_string().replace("\n", "\n" + indent)
```

(Choose `N` as you seem fit)